# how to get two values to get result in php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to get two values from a form in php which is weight and gender 
using jquery and ajax to show the price that corresponds to that gender and weight,

the mysql table looks like this

```
gender range1  range2  price
male     0       100     20
male    101      200     30
female   0       100     25
female  101      199     46
```

the php form looks like this

```
  <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender">
  <input type="number" name="weight">
 price <span id="result"></span>
<input type="button" herf="javascript:;" onclick="getprice" value="">
```

the ajax function looks like this

```
    function getprice (gender, whieght) {
        var str_num {
        "gender" : gender,
        "weight" : weight
       };
             $.ajax({ data: str_num, 
        url: 'selectprice.php',
        type: 'post'
        beforeSend: function() {
     $("#result").html("in progress..");},
           succes: function (reponse){
         $("result").html(reponse);
                  })}}
```

the selectprice.php looks like this

```
 $gender = $_GET["gender"];
  $weight = $_GET["weight"];
   $fetch = "SELECT * FROM table where gender like $gender and weight 
  >range1 and <range2"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $fetch) or die("Ocurrio un error en la 
  consulta SQL");
while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "".$row["price"]."";
    }
   echo $result;
```

when I click the button nothing happens, I could really use some help, thanks in an advance

Comment: Have you looked in the browser console to see what is being sent/happening? Have you looked in the web server log for errors? Not working in not very descriptive.

Comment: Your calling getprice() without any paramiters.

Answer (score 1):

You really packed the errors in.

```
<input type="text" name="gender" id="gender">
<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight">
price 
<input type="button" herf="javascript:;" onclick="getprice()" value="">


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
});
function getprice () {
    var str_num = {
        "gender" : $('#gender').val(),
        "weight" : $('#weight').val()
    };
    $.ajax({ 
        data: str_num, 
        url: 'selectprice.php',
        type: 'post',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#result").html("in progress..");
        },
        succes: function (reponse){
            $("result").html(reponse);
        }
    })
};

</script>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
//  ini_set('log_errors', true);

var_dump($_POST); // Your doing a post not a get in the javaacript.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your line:

```
url: 'selectprice.php?weight='+weight+'&gender='+gender,
```

Or you can pass `data` just after `url`

```
url: 'selectprice.php',
data: {weight:weight, gender,gender},
```

Comment: Specifically, the click handler that calls `getprice` doesn't pass anything in. You either need to pass those values (note the typo on *whieght*) or query those values in that function-  if not passing them in.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing "POST" and "GET" here.

If you want to use "GET" then follow Naveed's suggestion

If you want to use "POST" then find the two possible solutions below:

1) Easy one: Include your variables directly in data

```
function getprice (gender, weight) {

         $.ajax({ data: "gender" : gender,
    "weight" : weight, 
    url: 'selectprice.php',
    type: 'post'
    beforeSend: function() {
 $("#result").html("in progress..");},
       success: function (reponse){
     $("result").html(reponse);
              })}}
```

selectprice.php:

replace

```
 $gender = $_GET["gender"];  $weight = $_GET["weight"];
```

with

```
 $gender = $_POST["gender"];  $weight = $_POST["weight"];
```

2) Slightly complex one: Use stringify

```
function getprice (gender, weight) {
    var data={
    "gender" : gender,
    "weight" : weight
   };

var str_num = JSON.stringify(data);

         $.ajax({ data: str_num, 
    url: 'selectprice.php',
    type: 'post'
    beforeSend: function() {
 $("#result").html("in progress..");},
       success: function (reponse){
     $("result").html(reponse);
              })}}
```

selectprice.php:

replace

```
 $gender = $_GET["gender"];  $weight = $_GET["weight"];
```

with

```
$json_data_from_js= json_decode($_POST['data']);
$gender = $json_data_from_js->gender ;
$weight = $json_data_from_js-> weight;
```